# Give all users including anonymous ones the option to add nodes of certain content types to a list like "interested", at least once

Tags: nodes, commerce, javascript, ajax, 10

I'd like to give all users including anonymous ones the option to add nodes of certain content types to a list like "interested", at least once.

The logic is identical to that of a shopping cart in ecommerce websites **but this website is not ecommerce and there is no payment mechanism and even no `submit` button** so the user can just add each node at least once to the list, increment or decrement (`zero = deleted`).

How to do that if I want the data saved in Drupal database?

Comment: This sounds like something you would solve with vanilla JavaScript, nothing specific to Drupal. If the question is somehow specific to Drupal, apart from the JS being executed in HTML that happens to have been generated by Drupal, please edit to clarify what that is, and include detail of what you’ve tried so far

Comment: Flag module? https://www.drupal.org/project/flag

Comment: I can do it frontendly somehow yes but I would prefer to save the data in the Drupal database for potential marketing purposes and especially statistics.

Comment: Outside of user session how will this data be tracked reliably? Are they logging in? That is a totally different context than the original question.

Comment: No log in is necessary. I don't know if and how it can be possibly made to happen with the Drupal core and the role system.

Comment: No one is logged in then you can't apply roles or permissions. You would only be able to use private temp store service, or just use a cookie (or localStorage API in the browser) with JS.

Comment: But you can give almost the same permissions you will give to a regular registered user to an anonymous user, can you not?...

Comment: I think Drupal Commerce module will allow anonymous users with the right permissions to do something very similar so I assume this should be somehow possible as well, perhaps not with the core alone, though.

Comment: Asking a lot there so you have a lot of research to do.
you need to do this most likely with javascript and store in the users browser local storage ... because saving anonymous data is never the best idea .. 

so start googling JS local storage, then you can look in to creating custom modules with a controller, Ajax call that endpoint to save data on  a field on the user entity or in a custom table referencing the user 
I see you have asked many questions in last few days and can see you are keen however please self research is the best policy

Comment: @taggartJ when it comes to PHP I can't do research because I am not and never will be a PHP programmer. I mostly do JavaScript programming but instead of developing a JavaScript popup that will allow this with `localStorage` (which is a fine approach) I thought about some Drupal contrib module that will save me some time. I should check `flag` module that cilefen mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here we go:

Once you get through all the below you should be fine.

Do it all on the frontend then when want to save this data you now need to know

1. Look in to creating a custom module
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules
2. look in to how to create custom tables in a module (hook_schema) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_schema/9
3. look in to adding a controller to your new module
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/step-by-step-tutorial-hello-world/adding-a-basic-controller
4. Use Ajax to post Data to your new controller
   see this to get you to start Googling https://www.drupal.org/project/2958601/issues/3037313

take that posted data and save it to your custom table with reference to the user who is posting it which you can get in your controller eg \Drupal::currentUser();

5. Learn how to save the data https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/insert-queries
6. (Bonus) learn how to use this data with views  [https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8.2.x#:~:text=function%20hook_views_data&text=Describe%20data%20tables%20and%20fields,plugins%20topic%20for%20more%20information](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8.2.x#:%7E:text=function%20hook_views_data&text=Describe%20data%20tables%20and%20fields,plugins%20topic%20for%20more%20information).